# Unicode set notation meaning?

Tags: unicode

Where can I find info about the meaning of [this notation](https://unicode.org/reports/tr31/#Default_Identifier_Syntax)? What is "**\p**", "**{L}**", for example?

```
[\p{L}\p{Nl}\p{Other_ID_Start}-\p{Pattern_Syntax}-\p{Pattern_White_Space}]
```

Answer (score 0):

From context, it looks like the syntax

```
\p{name_of_character_class}
```

means “all characters from type `name_of_character_class`. The notation

```
[abc-x-y-z]
```

seems to mean “any character of type a, b, or c, but not type x, y, or z.” So the example above would be read as “any characters of type L, Nl, Other_ID_Start, except for characters that are Pattern_Syntax or Pattern_White_Space.”

Some of these groups are defined in the document itself. L and Nl, I think (?), are “lowercase” and “normalized lowercase,” but I’m not sure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: These are [Unicode "general categories"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category). `L` is Letter; `Nl` is Number/letter, an odd category that includes, for example, the roman numerals starting at U+2160.